# Google FCM endpoints stop responding when calling through a proxy API

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

We are facing an issue in which sometimes FCM.googleapis.com and iid.googlleapis.com stop responding. The behavior is completely unexpected. Suddenly it starts working and stops working giving connection timeout error. I am attaching the error screenshot below for reference.
[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate on the situation enviourment ? eg. how do you proxing , is there any intermediate dns resolver ?

Comment: We proxing the request by java code. I am attaching the code libraries below for reference. The same code works fine sometimes and stops working.
We using Proxy and HttpURLConnection libraries for proxing our request to FCM endpoints.

Proxy proxy
HttpURLConnection